# Functions question with absolute value

Tags: functions

The functions $f$ and $g$ are defined by 
$$ f:x \mapsto |x-a| + a $$

$$ g:x \mapsto 4x +a $$

(with every value of $x$)
where a is a positive constant

(a) On the same diagram, sketch the graphs of $f$ and $g$, showing clearly the coordinates of any points at which your graphs meet the axes.
(b) Use algebra to find, in terms of $a$, the coordinates of the point at which the graphs of $f$ and $g$ intersect.

Comment: I think if a>0 ,x coordinate of g(x) will run from 0 -> -∞, y coordinate of f(x) will change from 0-> + ∞

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set $f$ and $g$ equal and solve for $x$ (in terms of $a$) to get the $x$ coordinate of intersection points.
$$ |x-a| + a = 4x + a $$
$$ |x-a| = 4x $$
$$ \pm (x-a) = 4x $$
$$ -3x = a \implies x = -\frac{a}{3} \quad\text{ when } (x-a) \geq 0$$
$$ 5x = a \implies x = \frac{a}{5} \quad\text{ when } (x-a) < 0 $$

So the graphs of the functions intersect at $(-\frac{a}{3}, \,f(-\frac{a}{3}))$ when $a \leq 0$  and $(\frac{a}{5}, \,f(\frac{a}{5}))$ when $a \geq 0$

**Plotting the functions:** The plot of $f$ will look like the standard absolute value function ($f:x\mapsto |x|$) plot, which [looks like a V centered at the origin](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%7C). Except it will be translated to the right $a$ units and up $a$ units. So when $a=1$, it will be transformed to the right $1$ and up $1$.

The plot of $g$ is a line that crosses the $y$ axis at $a$ and has a slope of $4$. [An example where $a=1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x%2B1).

Comment: What 's about sketching?

Comment: @LáDốiTrá Do you know what the plot of the absolute value function looks like? ($f:x\mapsto |x|$)

Comment: sorry , I forgot all of them because I'm 20 years old :(( @@